# office 365 on Linux with wine

Tags: microsoft-office, linux-mint, office365

I am studying towards a degree with the open university. They have recently added access to office 365 as one of the benefits for their students which I can install on up to 5 devices.

When I log in, I have access to all the cloud based programs which work fine but I am keen to get it on my desktop.

I use linux mint and when I go to the download page it tells me that I can only install on PC or Mac.

I installed wine on Linux hoping that would make a difference but hasnt.

Is there anything I can do in order to get the program to download onto my desktop and then hopefully wine can help it to run

Comment: What happens if you run the installer directly with Wine? That's what I'd try first.

Comment: @AFH It appears that it is wine that is causing the issue and not playonlinux. It is wine that gives the program error

Comment: @acejavelin's comment says it is supported on Wine 3.0. I guess you need to make sure you are running this revision or later.

Comment: Codeweavers Crossover has Windows 10 support, but not yet Microsoft Office 365 if you are thinking of going down that route.

Answer (score 1):

Managed to get the program downloaded using a "User Agent Switcher" add on in Firefox. worked great, the program downloaded without any problems. My main issue now is getting the program installed using Playonlinux

Comment: The comment section to your question as a great deal of noise, much of the information you provided, should have been included in the question body. The majority of the comments to your question is just noise and is not necessary since any relevant information should already be contained within the question body.  The comment section is also difficult to follow, due to the compressed nature of the comments, due to length limitations of comments themselves.  You also want to run the application, which I would presume, is your actual question. Any event I reversed my vote.

Comment: @Ramhound running the application would potentially be my next question and we have touched on it in the comments but I think I now know what I need to do. The main thing here was getting the application downloaded as the website recognised that I was not running a MAC or Windows OS so I was keen to find out how to foll the website into thinking I was. which is where u`user agent switcher` came in :-)

Comment: Chrome has a built in user agent switcher, https://www.howtogeek.com/113439/how-to-change-your-browsers-user-agent-without-installing-any-extensions/ - I used IE11 to download the 32-bit version. The later versions of Brave Browser also can use this method.